# iOS-Not receiving crashes on Crashlytics when app is resigned

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I am using Crashlytics in my app to get crash reports. Now customer Resigned that app with different apple account. Now I am not getting crash reports. 
What I can do please suggest. I am searching everywhere but not getting anything exactly. 
TIA

Comment: does app transfer to new account or you upload it by diffrent app id?

Comment: @NitinGohel customer resigned the app with their apple account so app id is getting changed.

Comment: 1 -Go to Build Settings:
    Search for debug Information Format
    Make Sure DWARF is selected for debug mode.
2- In AppDelegate:
    `Fabric.sharedSDK().debug = true`

Comment: @KhushbooDhote then you must be setup fabrics with new build id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for their reply.I got my solution I just ask my customer for new bundle Id  and their apple login . After running on Xcode it automatically got registered to Fabric.

Answer (score 0):

May be in your app installation of fabric is not proper. you need to follow the step https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install. OR you need to test using this code https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/features

Comment: On my account I am getting crash reports but when they resigned I am not getting now.

Answer (score 0):

May be the dsym file which is necessary for the crash log is not properly uploaded on the Fabric, 
Please check whether it is uploaded or not. and the other reason for not getting the crash report the user had not given permission for reports on their device. 
If the app id is changed for the application than you have to change the key for new app id. 
If you have change the organisation for the application, Please see this doc 
https://docs.fabric.io/apple/fabric/settings/working-in-teams.html#adding-organizations

Answer (score 0):

As i can see that application bundle id change you must be setup fabric with new build id either via `cocoapods` or drag and drop `frameworks`.

As you need to remove existing app that is not longer available so you need to remove app from fabric and setup fabric like a new app setting your issue going to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

From your derived data you will find dSym files. Archive and upload to fabric in the settings section.
Once you have validated and created the IPA for upload.

1. RightClick Archive - Show in Finder
   [image: 1. RightClick Archive - Show in Finder]
2. RightClick Archive - Show Package Contents
   [image: 2. RightClick Archive - Show Package Contents]
3. Zip the dSYM files
   [image: 3. Zip the dSYM files]
4. Upload to Fabric in settings section
   [image: 4. Upload to Fabric in settings section]

Your should be able to receive crashes in fabric once this is done.